# Accessing the CAD programme with Python

Tags: python, automation, autocad, cad

I have the plan to create various automations, optimisations and possibly also buttons for the 2D CAD programme, Antlog One. Compared to more common CAD programs like AutoCAD, I haven't found any libraries that can be easily used in Python to access the program.
Is there a common way to program new commands and automations into CAD programs?
Preferably with Python, of course, but any other idea with another language would also be helpful.

I hope there is someone who can help me with this.

I have already created automations for AutoCAD with the Python pyautocad library. This worked without any major problems. Now I hope that something similar can be used for other programmes. Unfortunately, I have not yet found a general approach for such solutions.

Comment: Does Antlog One have a api you can connect to? (check documentation, ask vendor)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shrotter.

I have already searched in the documentation and the website and unfortunately found nothing.

But so far I understood an API so that data could be taken from the CAD system. But less the system with data from my program can feed. Would feeding via a suitable API also be possible?
I have now contacted the company and hope for an answer.

Would there be a possibility to come to a solution without API?